# A continuous embedding.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

If $2 \le q \le \infty$ and $2s >n$, then is there a continuous embedding $ H^s (\Bbb R^n ) \hookrightarrow L^q(\Bbb R^n) $ ? Here $H^s$ means a general Sobolev space for $s = 0,1,\cdots$.

Comment: I think the conclusion holds if and only if q=2

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Thank you for the comment! Would you recommend a book or some documents involving some Sobolev inequalities on the domain $\Bbb R^n$ ?

Comment: Maybe Evans' book _Partial differential equations_. I rememmber Willie Wong has written notes on Sobolev spaces, so the result is almost surely in these ones.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Thank you very much.